# How to use ToJson when using IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> to configure entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am following the announcement [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/) to convert some of my entities to be stored as JSON in my SQL server. I can see in the blog post how this can be done in the OnModelCreating method, but how exactly do we do this when using IEntityTypeConfiguration to configure the tables and properties?

I have a configuration class for my entity, implementing IEntityTypeConfiguration. I override the Configure method in there to configure the entity. I'd like one of the navigation properties of my entity to be stored as JSON in the same table instead of a separate table.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Please put the actual code you have tried and the one challenge with that code so we may best assist you here - not just a link to somewhere many will never visit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same way as you would do via `ModelBuilder` (apart from skipping the `Entity` call, based on [What's New](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#mapping-to-json-columns) example):

```cs
class AuthorCfg : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Author>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Author> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsOne(
            author => author.Contact, 
            ownedNavigationBuilder =>
            {
                ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
                ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(contactDetails => contactDetails.Address);
            });
    }
}
```

Note that [`RelationalOwnedNavigationBuilderExtensions.ToJson`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalownednavigationbuilderextensions.tojson?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationalownednavigationbuilderextensions-tojson(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-builders-ownednavigationbuilder)) is part of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` package so be sure that the project holding the configurations has it installed.

Comment: Thank you so much for mentionening the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`! It was missing from my project, you saved me a lot of time.